# javascript values gettng lost in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a "scrub" function that is restructuring an object and passing it back.
but I am getting "undefined" passed back, on some items that have a value being passed in.
Can someone explain what's is going on?

```js
user = {
  _id: '5...3',
  firstname: 'jp',
  lastname: 'abcd',
  email: 'jpabcd@yahoo.com',
  password: '...',
  role: 'Worker',
  __v: 0
}

cleanuser = scrub(user);

console.log('\n\n cleanuser ', cleanuser); // SEE BELOW "A"


function scrub(u) {

  console.log('\n\n SCRUB ', u); // SEE BELOW "B"

  let r = {
    _id: u['_id'],
    first_name: u['firstname'],
    last_name: u['lastname'],
    email: u['email'],
    role: u['role'],
    wtf: 'xxx'
  };

  return r;
}
```

```
"A" 
cleanuser { 
    _id: 5...3,
    first_name: undefined,
    last_name: undefined,
    email: 'jpabcd@yahoo.com',
    role: undefined
}


"B"
 SCRUB { 
    _id: 5...3,
    firstname: 'jp',
    lastname: 'abcd',
    email: 'jpabcd@yahoo.com',
    password: '...',
    role: 'Worker',
    __v: 0 
}
```

You can see "B" shows that 'firstname' and 'lastname' have a value passed into the "scrub" function...

and you can see "email" gets passed thru - but firstname, lastname and role got passed back out as undefined.

Well  - a couple responses, ay it's ok and something else is going on - Seems right as I've used this approach before without issue...

So here is the "full" context of the code...

```
function scrub(u) {

    console.log('\n\n SCRUB ', u );

    let r = {
        _id: u['_id'],
        first_name: u['firstname'],
        last_name: u['lastname'],
        email: u['email'],
        role: u['role'],
        wtf: 'wtf is going on - this has not happened before'
    };

    return r;
}


router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {


    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.getUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {

        console.log( '\n\n USER \n\n', user );

        if (err) {
            ... return error 
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {

            if (err) {
                ... return error 
            }

            if (isMatch) {
                // remove the password from the user obj so it's not passed in the token
                var cleanuser = scrub(user); 

                console.log( '\n\n cleanuser \n\n', cleanuser );

                ...return success - user

            } else {

                ...return

            }

        });

    });

})
```

Any ideas at all.??

Using NodeJS, Express

Comment: Running the snippet from your code it actually works. Do you have something else going on your real code?

Comment: There is something else going on here, as @luigibertaco said, your code snippets is working fine.

Comment: probably some asynchronous code you haven't shown is at the heart of this

Comment: Which framework, ORM did you use in your code/project?

Comment: nodeJS. express